# How to return 0 if return type is for example char

Tags: c#, types, return-type

I was wondering how in C# I can return 0 when an if condition in a function is not true.

```
char Foo(int a)
{
    if(a>0)
        return 'a';
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This shows an error because I can't return 0 like that.

Of course I can do something like

```
const char NULL = 'b';
```

but I hope there is better solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to return '0' or '\0' (ASCII null character)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Why is the `else` part returning something different

Comment: You get to pick one return type, and that return type better make sense for all normal returns from your function. So, if `char` isn't a good fit because you want to be able to return a `0` then pick a different return type.

Comment: I would like to check if everything went right in a function. For example: if ok, return an array, else return 0. It would be really handy.

Comment: If something didn't go right, you should through and `Exception`

Comment: If you would like to check if everything went right in a function use Console.log("line x blabla") no ?

Comment: Thanks 3dd, it's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @XyzAbc This makes no sense. What are you really trying to do? You are comparing an *int* against zero and returning an arbitrary character in one case, or another int in another case? Why? Why not return a boolean?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos it's just a stupid example, I just wanted to have 1 ccondition and char return type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it nullable.

```
char? Foo(int a)
{
    if(a>0)
        return 'a';
    else
        return null;
}
```

That way, you'll either get a valid `char`, or a `null`, so you can distinguish between the two cases with no ambiguity.

Comment: Wow, it's pretty cool. But throwing an exception is probably better approach?

Comment: It might be. I would say it depends on calling code, and whether you consider `a<=0` an invalid argument.

Answer (score 2):

If the else part is an exceptional case throw and `Exception`.

```
char Foo(int a)
{  
if(a>0)
    return 'a';
else
    throw new Exception("YOUR ERROR MESSAGE");
}
```

If the else part can occur more frequently change the return type to return a nullable i.e. `char?`

```
char? Foo(int a)
{  
if(a>0)
    return 'a';
else
    return null;
}
```

This way the calling code can decide how to handle the invalid state without having to use `try{}catch{}`

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
char Foo(int a)
{
  if ( a > 0 )
    return 'a';
  else
    return '\0';
    // or: throw new InvalidOperationException("ERROR MESSAGE!");
}
```

Or use an `out` Parameter and `bool` as return type

```
bool TryFoo(int a, out char outChar)
{
  if (a > 0)
  {
    outChar = 'a';
    return true;
  }
  outChar = '\0';
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Best answer! I would do both with the usual style (Try...): `char MakeChar(int a)` and `bool TryMakeChar(int a, out char c)`

Comment: You still have to set `outChar` to something if `a <= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a default value:

```
char Foo(int a)
{
    if (a > 0)
        return 'a';
    else
        return default(char);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Tester-Doer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx)-apporach:

```
bool TryFoo(int a, out char val)
{
    if (a > 0) val = 'a';
    else a = default(char);

    return a > 0;
}
```

Now you may first check if `a` is a valid input for the method:

```
char val;
if (TryFoo(-5, out val)) 
{
    // do something with your value
}
```

Comment: You're not returning a value, missing `return a > 0;` at the end?

Comment: @HjalmarZ Indeed, changed